# Rails HABTM and belongs_to for associating users/projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a `User` and `Project` model. A user can have multiple projects, and a project can have multiple users. This of course is simple with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. My problem is that I'd also like to track the user who created the project. This would be simple with a `belongs_to :user` for my `Project` model. The problem then is that doing a `has_many :projects` for a `User` when a user already has a HABTM relationship with a `Project` makes little sense.

Here's what I would eventually like to achieve:

```
# building a project with the currently logged in user
current_user.projects.build(...)

# now when a user wants to add another user to this project
project = current_user.projects.find(...)
project.users << User.find(...)

# grabbing information
some_project.user  #=> The user who created this project
some_project.users #=> The array of User objects associated
some_user.projects #=> The array of Project objects associated
```

In the future it's likely a `User` will have the same sort of relationship with a `Group`, where a `User` would both have many and belong to many groups. But again I would also like to track the **creator** of this `Group`.

It's quite likely I'm missing something. What's a common way to achieve this?

If it helps to clarify, a possible configuration is laid out below:

- Group

  - has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  - belongs_to :user
  - has_many :projects
  - Only a `User` should have the ability to create a `Group`
- User

  - has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  - has_many :projects
  - Can great a group or a project, and can also belong to both
- Project

  - has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  - belongs_to :group
  - both a `User` and a `Group` should have the ability to create a `Project`

I've also tried doing simple `has_and_belongs_to_many` for each association and including a `creator_id` for example, and tracking this myself. For example.. `Project.create(:creator_id => current_user.id)` but this seemed hackish and I was sure they would be a better way to do this. Apologies for my ignorance if I've missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading this again you want to have one owner of the project, either a group or a user. Store that as a polymorphic belongs_to relationship from the project model. ie. owner_type => 'User'/'Group' owner_id => 123

Other users associated with the group are many to many so you need a join table.

Your group model is a separate model with a many to many relationship with users so you can simply store the user who created it as a field of the group model ie. :user_id 123.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer. I think you're right for what I need, I was looking for more of a specific answer as I'm a little confused with relationships between these 3 models, Ryan uses 2 and their relationship is a little different. I'm going to give it today to see if anyone else answers. Thanks again

Comment: Have a look at my edit. Sorry but I think I was leading you down the wrong path previously as I skimmed your question. Let me know if you don't understand anything. Polymorphism might need some explanation so there's a railscast on it http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association